# Windows Store App ListView

Tags: xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I've a ListView that its items are a set of RadioButtons, the ListView is bonded to a list of 100 strings when I select a radio button let say from the first item , and maybe the second and the third, everything work just fine. But when I scroll for the maybe the 50th item or when I select a radiobutton in any item not appearing the first page, the selection of the first item which are in the previous page is just deselected, as if the listview rendered the items again and forgot about may manipulation

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="list" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <RadioButton Template="{StaticResource CheckBoxTemplate2}" Foreground="Orange" Content="Test" Label="YOK" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Canvas.ZIndex="12" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Advantage-SemiBold"  Checked="BetRadioButton_Checked_1" Click="x1_Click"  />
                    <RadioButton x:Name="x2" Template="{StaticResource CheckBoxTemplate2}" Foreground="Orange" Content="Test" Label="YOK" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Canvas.ZIndex="12" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Advantage-SemiBold"  Checked="BetRadioButton_Checked_1" Click="x1_Click"  />
                    <RadioButton x:Name="x3" Template="{StaticResource CheckBoxTemplate2}" Foreground="Orange" Content="Test" Label="YOK" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Canvas.ZIndex="12" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Advantage-SemiBold"  Checked="BetRadioButton_Checked_1"  Click="x1_Click"  />
                    <RadioButton x:Name="x4" Template="{StaticResource CheckBoxTemplate2}" Foreground="Orange" Content="Test" Label="YOK" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Canvas.ZIndex="12" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Advantage-SemiBold"  Checked="BetRadioButton_Checked_1"  Click="x1_Click"  />
                    <RadioButton x:Name="x5" Template="{StaticResource CheckBoxTemplate2}" Foreground="Orange" Content="Test" Label="YOK" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Canvas.ZIndex="12" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Advantage-SemiBold"  Checked="BetRadioButton_Checked_1"  Click="x1_Click"  />
                    <RadioButton x:Name="x6" Template="{StaticResource CheckBoxTemplate2}" Foreground="Orange" Content="Test" Label="YOK" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Canvas.ZIndex="12" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Advantage-SemiBold"  Checked="BetRadioButton_Checked_1"  Click="x1_Click"  />
                    <RadioButton x:Name="x7" Template="{StaticResource CheckBoxTemplate2}" Foreground="Orange" Content="Test" Label="YOK" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Canvas.ZIndex="12" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Advantage-SemiBold"  Checked="BetRadioButton_Checked_1"  Click="x1_Click"  />

                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>



list.DataContext = new List<String>() { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your problem is that all of your `RadioButton`s have the same `GroupName`.  The default `GroupName` for radio buttons is null, so all your `RadioButtons` have the same `GroupName`.  To fix this you need to come up with a unique `GroupName` for each item in your `ListView`.  Also, all of your `Checked` properties are bound to the same property.  Are you maybe wanting a `CheckBox` instead of a `RadioButton`?

Comment: LOL, thanks for answer, but the problem is a little bit advanced. but thanks anyway.